# cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd, extentreports, maven-dependency

I am running the script using Cucumber in BDD Framework and I am using Extent Reports plugin to create the execution report.

I've created the test runner class as below:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

import com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.Reporter;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Cucumber - BDD\\CucumberPOM\\src\\main\\java\\com\\qa\\features\\DemoSite.feature"//path of the feature files
        ,glue = {"com/qa/stepDefinitions"} //path of the step definition files
        ,plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/html/ExtentReport.html"}
    //  ,plugin = {"pretty","html:test-output","json:json_output/cucumber.json","junit:junit_output/cucumber.xml"} //to generate diff types of reporting
        ,monochrome =true //display the console output in a proper readable format
        ,strict=true //it will check if any step is not defined in step definition file
        ,dryRun = false  //to check the mapping is proper btw feature file and step defn file
        //,tags = {"@FuntionalTest" , "~@SmokeTest" , "~@End2EndTest"}
        )

public class TestRunner {

    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/extent-config.xml"));
    }  

}
```

I have included the below dependency for the Extent report in the POM.xml file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
<version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

when I execute the above runner class im getting error - cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter

Comment: Could anyone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having this similar issue, and to solve it I've changed the plugin in `@CucumberOptions`:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = { "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:path/report.html"}
)
```

But still, I'm facing another issues right now. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. I tried adding the vimalselvam in my plugin, but it diid not work for me :(

Comment: Do what the comment below said, change the cucumber to version 4 (io.cucumber). Use the plugin com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:{path to generate the report}. And within the TestRunner, tag the @BeforeClass in a method to generate the report. I did the following: ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        extentReports.flush();
        extentReports.setGherkinDialect("pt");   //this last one is to change to my language (portuguese). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter is not supported in Cucumber version 4. If you are using cucumber 4, you have to use Cucumber Extent Adapter as plugin. see detailed documentation as how to use it in your framework here - http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/cucumber4.html